# return column name of min greater than 0 pandas

Tags: pandas, minimum

I have a dataframe with one date column and rest numeric columns, something like this

```
   date         col1        col2        col3          col4
2020-1-30        0            1           2             3
2020-2-1         0            2           3             4
2020-2-2         0            2           2             5
```

I want to now find the name of the column which gives me minimum sum per column, but only when greater than 0. So in the above case, I want it to give me col2 as a result because the sum of this (5) is least of all other columns other than col1 which is 0. Appreciate any help with this

Comment: there are several steps top this process. have you tried any of them?

Comment: So what is col1 was 1, 2, 0? you would still skip the column?

Comment: no, if col1 was 1,2,0, its sum would be 3 which would be the minimum of all columns, so in that case I would like col1 returned please. Also, if the sum of two individual columns is same as the minimum, I would like both column names returned please (for eg. if col2 sum is 3 and also col4 sum is 3 and 3 is minimum of sums of all individual columns, I would like returned both col2 and col4 as a result please)

Comment: So you only ignore a column if it's all zeros?

Comment: yes, in other words, I want to ignore if the sum of the column is 0

Answer (score 3):

I would use:

```
# get only numeric columns
df2 = df.select_dtypes('number')

# drop the columns with 0, compute the sum
# get index of min
out = df2.loc[:, df2.ne(0).all()].sum().idxmin()
```

If you want to ignore a column only if all values are 0, use `any` in place of `all`:

```
df2.loc[:, df2.ne(0).any()].sum().idxmin()
```

Output: `'col2'`

#### all minima

```
# get only numeric columns
df2 = df.select_dtypes('number')

# drop the columns with 0, compute the sum
s = df2.loc[:, df2.ne(0).any()].sum() 

# get all minimal
out = s[s.eq(s.min())].index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
['col2']
```

Comment: thank you so much. in case where more than one column gives same sum, is there a way to return both column names please?

Comment: Yes, `s = df2.loc[:, df2.ne(0).all()].sum() ; out = s[s.eq(s.max())]`

Comment: this is returning me empty []

Comment: It works well for me, please double check my update

Comment: tried several times also with minor changes, still returns Series([], dtype: float64) for me

Comment: Can you please provide your input as DataFrame constuctor (`df.to_dict()`)? Can you also double check that you have numeric types?